# import old data from postgres to elasticsearch

Tags: database, postgresql, elasticsearch, import, export

I have a lot of data in my postgres database( on a remote). This is the data of the past 1 year, and I want to push it to elasticsearch now.

The data has a time field in it in this format `2016-09-07 19:26:36.817039+00`.

I want this to be the timefield(`@timestamp`) in elasticsearch. So that I can view it in kibana, and see some visualizations over the last year.

I need help on how do I push all this data efficiently. I cannot get that how do I get all this data from postgres.

I know we can inject data via jdbc plugin, but I think I cannot create my  `@timestamp` field with that.

I also know about zombodb but not sure if that also gives me feature to give my own timefield.

Also, the data is in bulk, so I am looking for an efficient solution

I need help on how I can do this. So, suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

> I know we can inject data via jdbc plugin, but I think I cannot create
>   my  `@timestamp` field with that.

This should be doable with Logstash. The first starting point should probably be [this blog post](https://www.elastic.co/blog/logstash-jdbc-input-plugin). And remember that Logstash always consists of 3 parts:

1. Input: [JDBC input](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/5.5/plugins-inputs-jdbc.html). If you only need to import once, skip the `schedule` otherwise set the right timing in cron syntax.
2. Filter: This one is not part of the blog post. You will need to use the [Date filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/5.5/plugins-filters-date.html) to set the right `@timestamp` value — adding an example at the end.
3. Output: This is simply the [Elasticsearch output](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/5.5/plugins-outputs-elasticsearch.html).

This will depend on the format and field name of the timestamp value in PostgreSQL, but the filter part should look something like this:

```
date {
   match => ["your_date_field", "dd-mm-YYYY HH:mm:ss"]
   remove_field => "your_date_field" # Remove now redundant field, since we're storing it in @timestamp (the default target of date)
}
```

If you're concerned with the performance:

- You will need to set the right [`jdbc_fetch_size`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/5.5/plugins-inputs-jdbc.html#plugins-inputs-jdbc-jdbc_fetch_size).
- Elasticsearch output is [batched by default](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/5.5/plugins-outputs-elasticsearch.html#_batch_sizes).